# Why i cannot send email via ajax (Without Form)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Firstly, thanks because viewing my question here. My problem is i cannot send email through my ajax request. Actually, my ajax request to post email is in another ajax request.

Here is my code for my ajax :

```js
$.ajax({
            url: 'creating_bill.php',
            data: { 
                paid_amount : JSON.stringify(jumlah_semua),
                email : emel,
                name : nama
            },
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            
            success: function (data) {
                id = data.id;
                url = data.url;
                   
               confirm('Terima Kasih ! Sila membuat pembayaran dengan segera.');          
               window.open(data.url, '_blank');
                setTimeout(checkBillStatus, 1000);

                $('li#progress2').removeClass('active').next().addClass("active");
               $('.container_waiting').fadeIn();
                $('#cara_pembayaran_form').fadeOut();
                
                     var  name =$('input#nama').val();
                     var   phone =$('input#phone').val();
                     var  negeri =$('input#negeri').val();
                     var   bandar =$('input#bandar').val();
                     var   poskod = $('input#poskod').val();
                     var   alamat =$('input#alamat').val();
                     var   emel = $('input#emel').val();
                     var   jumlah = $('input#jumlah_semua').val();
                     var   bill_url = url;
                     
                     // Here is my ajax request to send email
                    $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "send_bill_email.php",
                            data: {
                                name : name,
                                phone : phone,
                                negeri : negeri,
                                bandar : bandar,
                                poskod : poskod,
                                alamat : alamat,
                                emel : emel,
                                jumlah : jumlah,
                                bill_url : bill_url
                            },
                            dataType:"json",
                            success: function(data2){
                                console.log("Success!");
                            }
                        });
            },
            async: false,
            error: function(data) {
                handleRequestError(data);
            }
            
            
        })   
}
```

and this is my code in php :

```html
<?php
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    $email = $_POST['emel'];
    $address = $_POST['alamat'];
    $poskod = $_POST['poskod'];
    $negeri = $_POST['negeri'];
    $bandar = $_POST['bandar'];
    $jumlah_harga = $_POST['jumlah'];
    $bill_url = $_POST['bill_url'];

    $to =  $email; 

    // Subject
    $subject = 'FROM: Ordering System From - ' . $name;

    // Message
    $message = '
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>' . $subject . '</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <p>Nama: ' . $name . '</p>
            <p>Telefon: ' . $phone . '</p>
            <p>Email: ' . $email . '</p>
            <p>Alamat: ' . $address . '</p>
            <p>Poskod: ' . $poskod . '</p>
            <p>Negeri: ' . $negeri . '</p>
            <p>Bandar: ' . $bandar . '</p>
            <p>Jumlah Harga: ' . $jumlah_harga . '</p>
            <p>Bill url: ' . $bill_url . '</p>
        </body>
    </html>
    ';

    // To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
    $headers[] = 'MIME-Version: 1.0';
    $headers[] = 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1';

    // Additional headers
    $headers[] = 'From: ' . $name . ' <' . $email . '>';

    // Mail it
    mail($to, $subject, $message, implode("\r\n", $headers));

?>
```

Thank you for your time. I hope there is someone that could help me solve this.

Comment: what's the exact problem?

Comment: The problem is the ajax request to send email is not working. I dont know why maybe i have error in my code. I try console.log and put success & error in ajax code but they didnt detect anythings @Maximus

Comment: does php script get \executed?

Comment: I dont really know how to check. But it should be executed since ajax show no errors. @Maximus

Comment: how do you run the script? apache?

Comment: I run my script from my hosting. Yes, it use apache. @Maximus

Comment: well, your problem should be split into smaller pieces, try sending request through POSTMAN, CURl or other client and see if sends email. Make sure that PHP script is working fine. Then start investigating client side

Comment: I don't think there is any issue with your javascript code. check your SMTP server configuration in php.ini file becuase you are directly using mail function. Another way to send mail using PHPMailer class.

Comment: Glad to know there's no issues with my javascript code. Maybe its because of my php code. But, i dont know how to check this. Is there any other way to send email without mail function ? @gyaan

Comment: try this https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try to wrap your entire to php code to this

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
 //YOUR CODE GOES HERE 
}
```

also i strongly suggest to use the development window of your browser to see the process.